# iOS10: German Localization not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization, localizable.strings

Currently my app supports `English` & `German` `localization` and I've used `Localizable.strings` for this purpose. You can see the project settings and Localizable in pictures below.
[image]

[image]

Now I've issues in German localizations. In iPhone there are 4 variations of German language. 
[image]

App runs fine in first and the last 2 but it's not localized in Deutsch (Deutschland). Can someone know what's the reason? Also when I sewlected this variation then Main german language selection is no more available in languages.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head arouind the possible reasons, I tried one thing which worked. I added another localizable for Germany (Germany).
[image]

But I still don't know the original reason of the problem. Ideally one German localization should have sufficed for all variations of language.

Answer (score 1):

There are some languages that have regional variants in iOS, starting in iOS 9. Sometimes, when you tap a language, another menu will appear with some regional variants. Here are some examples with regional variants.

## **Deutsch**

- Deutschland
- Österreich
- Schweiz

## **English**

- Australia
- Canada
- India
- Ireland
- New Zealand
- Singapore
- South Africa
- United Kingdom
- United States

## **Español**

- Argentina
- Bolivia
- Chile
- Costa Rica
- Ecuador
- El Salvador
- España
- Estados Unidos
- Guatemala
- Honduras
- Latinoamérica
- México
- Nicaragua
- Panamá
- Paraguay
- Perú
- Puerto Rico
- República Dominicana
- Uruguay
- Venezuela

## **Français**

- Belgique
- Canada
- France
- Suisse

## **Italiano**

- Italia
- Svizzera

## **Nederlands**

- België
- Nederland

## **繁體中文**

- 台灣
- 澳門
- 香港

Remember to choose the closest regional variant if you're localizing an app with the languages listed above.